# How to grab specific segments of M3U8 via ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, m3u8

I recently asked baout how I could download segments of an online m3u8 file, and someone pointed out that this could be accomplished via `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i [LINK] -codec copy [OUTPUT FILE] #downloads only audio segments;
ffmpeg -i [LINK] -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy -c copy -crf 50 [OUTPUT] #downloads audio and video segments
```

For those who aren't familiar, m3u8 is formatted kinda of like a "playlist", with an m3u8 file pointing to a bunch of smaller "segments" which are pieced together to form the whole of the video. As a result, it's completely possible to halt the above commands partway through their execution and still produce a watchable video (i.e. one that will be interpreted correctly by video editors).

I'm wondering if there's a built-in method with `ffmpeg` that allows me to grab segments N-M of a given m3u8. If there are methods outside of `ffmpeg`, feel free to mention them as well. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After having looked into it, I can say that this isn't possible via `ffmpeg`. You could theoretically use the `-ss` and `-t` parameters to specify a starting point and duration, but `ffmpeg` appears to look at every clip up until the specified endpoint, making the download process prohibitively long.

If you want to download only a specific number of segments, you need to look at the m3u8 file, find its associated media list, and download segments from that media list.